# What is the apex angle of the cone of positive semidefinite matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, angle, positive-semidefinite, convex-cone

Let $\def\S{\mathbf S}\S^n$ be the linear space of symmetric $n \times n$ matrices and $\S_+^n$ be the subset of positive semidefinite matrices. It is well-known that $\S_+^n$ is a convex cone in $\S^n$. In order to get a better geometric understanding of this object, I asked myself what the [apex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apex_(geometry)) angle of this cone might be.

We use the inner product $\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}\def\<{\langle}\def\>{\rangle}\<A,B\>=\tr(AB)$, where $\tr(A)$ is the trace of $A$.

> The *apex angle* $\theta$ of $\S_+^n$ is the biggest value of $\arccos\<A_1,A_2\>$ for $A_i\in\S_+^n$ with $\<A_i,A_i\>=1$.

---

**My best result so far**

Let $\def\E{\mathbf E}\E$ be some Euclidean space and $S\subset \E$ a proper subspace. Let $A_1\in\S_+^n$ be the orthogonal projection onto $S$ and $A_2\in\S_+^n$ the orthogonal projection onto the orthogonal complement $S^\bot$. Then $\<A_i,A_i\>=1$ but $A_1A_2=0$, hence $\<A_1,A_2\>=\tr(A_1A_2)=0$.

So we have that $\theta\ge 90^\circ$. Can we do better? Especially, can we have $\tr(A_1A_2)<0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to have $\operatorname{tr}(A_1A_2) < 0$ if each $A_i$ is positive semidefinite.

A proof I like is as follows: note that (via the spectral theorem, for instance) we may decompose $A_2$ into
$$
A_2 = \sum_{k=1}^n x_kx_k^T, \qquad x_k \in \Bbb R^n
$$
With that, we find that
$$
\operatorname{tr}(A_1A_2) = 
\operatorname{tr}\left(A_1\sum_{k=1}^n x_kx_k^T\right) = 
\sum_{k=1}^n \operatorname{tr}(A_1x_kx_k^T) = 
\sum_{k=1}^n \operatorname{tr}(x_k^TA_1x_k) = \\
\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^TA_1x_k \geq 0
$$

Comment: Another notable result is that the cone $S_+^n$ is [self-dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_cone_and_polar_cone#Self-dual_cones)

Comment: Very nice proof! Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem.  Off the top of my head, I believe that all self-dual (closed, convex) cones have a $90^\circ$ apex angle, but that's just a hunch.

Comment: Yeah, I had the same thought. I will think about it.